# What is the meaning of this Upstart init error?

Tags: upstart

```
$ start playframework
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", 
sender=":1.6" (uid=1000 pid=1080 comm="start portal ") 
interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" 
requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart"
(uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
```

I'm trying to get [playframework](http://www.playframework.org/) to start using [this Upstart script](https://gist.github.com/2029862).

I saw similar errors posted around the web, and here, but never found a general explaination of what they mean. Does it mean the process that's being started returned an error? What's the general way to debug these kinds of errors?

Comment: It seems I was missing a `sudo`, as in `sudo start playframework`. I still don't know exactly what the above cryptic message means, so I'll leave this question up here.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

It means you don't have permissions to tell Upstart what to do. As you said, you're missing `sudo` and normal user has no permissions to start or stop system jobs. The cryptic string is just very engineerish (and exact) way to say it :-)

Comment: Linux usability still has a long way to go...

Comment: Linux usability doesn't fit in the same sentence as system administration :-) Command line tools are supposed to give you exact problem descriptions, otherwise they're useless. I agree though that this specific error message could be said differently.

Comment: @Tuminoid out of interested, can you describe that error message.  What tells you that you lack sufficient privileges?

Comment: "Rejected send message" meaning "permission denied" is standard way of expressing "missing root privileges" when receiver is pid=1 uid=0 (root).

Comment: Hmm...sadly for me adding sudo then gives me "start: Job failed to start" w/o any useful info on why it failed to start :(

Comment: @David add `console log` stanza and check `/var/log/upstart/<job>.log` for logs.